# Node.js net.socket never connects, gives no error

Tags: node.js

I wave written the following piece of code:

```
var net = require('net');

const checkSum = (msg) => {
    if (msg.length === 0) return 256;

    let hash = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        let char = msg.charCodeAt(i);
        hash += char;
    }

    hash &= 0xFF;
    hash = 0x100 - hash;

    return hash;
}

const sendAndGetReply = (msg, ip, port) => {
    const message = msg + checkSum(msg).toString();

    var client = new net.Socket()
    var reply = "";
    var rts = false;

    console.log(`trying to connect ${ip}:${port}`);
    client.connect(port, ip)
        .on('connect', function () {
            console.log('Connected');
            client.write(message);
        })
        .on('error', e => console.log(e))
        .on('data', function (data) {
            reply = data
            client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
        })
        .on('close', function () {
            rts = true;
        });
    while (!rts) {

    }
    return reply;
}

const home = (serial, ip, port) => {
    const message = `HOME,${serial},`;
    const homeReply = sendAndGetReply(
        message,
        ip,
        port
    );
    console.log(homeReply);
    if (homeReply != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

home("004-301023", "192.168.13.43", 80);
```

It is essentially trying to connect to a motion card in my LAN and send a home command. The message `trying to connect 192.168.13.43:80` is displayed. After that, no errors come up, but neither does the 'Connected ever appear. I am desperate...

I am using Node.js v19.1.0
The host is ping-able from the same machine and a similar python script does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting stuck in your infinite while loop. Lose it, javascript doesn't work like that. There are two ways to achieve what you're going for: either [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) or an [async function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

**Option 1. Callback**:

```js
const sendAndGetReply = (msg, ip, port, cb) => {
    const message = msg + checkSum(msg).toString();

    var client = new net.Socket()

    console.log(`trying to connect ${ip}:${port}`);
    var replay = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        client.connect(port, ip)
        .on('connect', function () {
            console.log('Connected');
            client.write(message);
        })
        .on('error', e => cb(e))
        .on('data', function (data) {
            client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
            cb(null,data);
        })
}

// ...

const homeReply = sendAndGetReply(
        message,
        ip,
        port,
        (err,data) => { if(err) console.error(err); else console.log(data) }
    );
```

**Option 2. Async**:

```js
const sendAndGetReply = async (msg, ip, port) => {
    const message = msg + checkSum(msg).toString();

    var client = new net.Socket()

    console.log(`trying to connect ${ip}:${port}`);
    var reply = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      client.connect(port, ip)
        .on('connect', function () {
            console.log('Connected');
            client.write(message);
        })
        .on('error', reject)
        .on('data', function (data) {
            client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
    return reply;
}

// ...

const homeReply = await sendAndGetReply(
        message,
        ip,
        port
    );
```

Comment: Allowed myself to edit and make your answer a little clearer just to make sure someone won't try to implement **both** ways :)

Comment: I need to buy you guys some beer! I always tried some Promise approach that would never work. I'm working in Astronomy and I'm probably the first one to write an instrument controller in Node+React+Mongo, instead of a python CLI.

Comment: Good look. As an aside; the way the example is currently written you'll be stuck forever if you don't get a response from the server, you probably want to add protection for that. Have a look at Promise.race() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race